# How to open files from a very large folder quickly?

Tags: python, file, ntfs

I have a folder with about 220,000 text files. I need to open them in a certain order, and do something with the content. At the moment, I just use `open`, and it takes, on average, about half a second to open a file. Is there any faster way to do it?

If it matters - I'm on Windows.

Comment: Oh, my, my, my. A quarter million files in a single NTFS directory is definitely in talking burro territory. It's not amazing it works badly. It's amazing it works at all. Hopefully you can reorganize this. Can you zip the lot of them, move them to a Linux extfs4 file system, unzip them, and do your work there?

Comment: @OllieJones Unfortunately, that's going to be hard in my situation, so I'll keep that as a last resort, if nothing else works out...

Comment: If only there was some mechanism in which a filesystem could let the user maintain smaller groups of items so that they're not all collated in one place. Surely such technology could never exist...

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problems in the past. In my case it was a directory full of jpeg images I was trying to process.  They had similar names in the first few characters of the filenames, and that caused real performance trouble.

There's a legacy-compatibility feature in NTFS that assigns each filename a shadow filename that complies with the old DOS 8.3 filename limitation. Yep, it used to be that you could only name a file `ABCDEFGH.EXT`, and file names couldn't be longer.  The legacy-compatility feature assigns a goofy alias name to every file that doesn't match 8.3, giving it a name like `ABCDEF~1.EXT`. When you have a lot of files the performance of this compatibility feature is talking-burro horrible.

I just checked my relatively new Windows 7 install, and the compatibility feature is still turned on.

You can turn off this feature for a whole volume using the `fsutil` program [which you can read about here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621566.aspx).  You'll need a cmd or powershell window with admin privileges to do this.

```
 fsutil 8dot3name query h:
```

will tell you whether this feature is enabled on your h drive.

```
 fsutil 8dot3name set h: 1
```

will disable it entirely on your h drive. That might be destructive on your boot drive, especially if you have old-timey legacy software.  When I implemented this, I made sure my directories containing tons of files were on a non-boot drive, and I left the boot drive alone.

You can strip the shadow 8.3 names from "all files that are located in a directory path" with this command

```
 fsutil 8dot3name strip /s h:\data\transactions
```

Stripping those names from your files in your big directory may help performance. (Back up the directory first, maybe with 7zip or something).

**Read the documentation for [fsutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621566.aspx) before stripping those legacy filenames!**

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of the underlying file system. Use a file system that is better suited for large amount of files. Built a directory tree, sort the files into directories after the first, second, third ... character of the filename.

Comment: This is not a problem of the underlying file system.  This is an organization problem, and OP apparently has a disorganized mess.  More information might help.

Comment: The comment about the OP is definitely true. What information might help?

Comment: If you sort all your files in directories named after the first two characters of the file, you get 1000 directories with 220 files each, and you don't have problems with searching filenames in a linear list, as the file system is organized.

Comment: @Daniel I felt quite stupid for not thinking of that myself. So I made 100 directories, each with one more level of subdirectories. Now I get an average of a bit more than 1 second per file. I have to find out what happens there...